# MongoDB: cannot upsert if query object and update object contain a same property , 'Cannot apply $addToSet modifier to non-array'

Tags: regex, mongodb, updates, insert-update, upsert

I want to execute a complex upsert, made by the following elements:

- query on a field *f* by regex
- update of the same field *f* (that is specified in the query object too)

Like this:

```
db.coll.update({ prop: /valueprop/i } , { $addToSet:{ prop:'a value' }  } , true, false)
```

My expectation would be that if the document does not exist in the collection it is inserted with *prop* field equals to 'a value'; in other words it should insert a document with value of *prop* field that is the one specified in the update object.

Instead it throws `Cannot apply $addToSet modifier to non-array` , like if it tries to update the field prop with the value specified in the query object (that is a RegExp object) instead of using the value specified in the update object.

Isn't it a bug?

Comment: This stems down the the fact that without a $set MongoDB will actually use both arguments to form a new document

Comment: $set and $addToSet should work at the same way, they have only different semantics but both should update only the fields that they specify. Or how should be the query according to your suggestion?

Comment: I must admit I am only going by the PHP documentation which actually describes this, which made me think it is specific to using $set, I don't actually have a MongoDB install to test this with atm

Comment: Oh of course, $addToSet doesn't work on insert as well, that might be why it can't understand it

Comment: Oh wait I just realised I read your question wrong, I assumed the title and didn't fully read the body. I think your gonna need an $setOnInsert here to make prop and array

Comment: It seems a bug as specified here https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3946 
Searching for a workaround

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround is using `$all` keyword in the query object  in the following way

```
db.cancellami.update({prop:{$in:[/regex_value/i]}},{ $addToSet:{prop:'a value'}} ,true,false)
```

Comment: Weird I didn't actually know they had classed it as a bug now, I guess they gave in to popular demand there

Answer (score 0):

As said in the documentation $addToSet operator adds a value into an array only if the value is not in the array already: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/#up._S_addToSet

Your *prop* value is an string so you couldn't use $addToSet. Instead of this you could do the next:

```
db.collection.update({prop:/valueprop/i},{$set:{prop:['a value']}}, true, false)
```

**Update:**
In case you need to ensure that are not going to exist duplicates in your arrays, you must first update all your documents to convert them into arrays with something like this:

```
db.collection.find({ $where : "isString(this.prop)"}).forEach(function (doc) {
       doc.prop = [doc.prop];
       db.collection.save(doc); 
})
```

And then you will be able to execute the next to ensure you'll always update only array fields and no errors will be found:

```
db.collection.update({ $where : "Array.isArray(this.prop)"},{$addToSet:{prop:'a value'}}, true, false)
```

Comment: Your solution is not good. Imagine if the document is already in the collection, so imagine the upsert is an update operation. In this case, your solution is going to overwrite the existing values in the prop field, while I want to add new values keeping the already existintg ones.

Comment: @GiovanniBitliner you are right I've update the answer to cover that case. Regards

Comment: NEVER DO A $WHERE. Honestly this is asking for trouble. It is a full table scan for one, not only that but you re-eval() that JS expression for every document in the collection.

Comment: So... propouse a solution @Sammye